# How do I print dynamic/1 in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to print these all names under each dynamic/1. For example I want to print all names of male under one query for print all males in Prolog.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The supplied code works with SWI-Prolog, don't know if this works with other Prolog systems but the basis of the code should be portable.

This is from actual code I use daily so it more production quality code than simple answer code but the basis is to use [functor/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=functor/3) to get a head and then use the head in [forall/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2) to get the rules ([rule/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=rule/2)) and [format/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/3) to output each rule. Normally a rule is a head and body but since this is outputting facts only the heads are output. To convert the rules to individual values [=../2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2) is used. This uses [library(options)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=option). This also uses [current_predicate/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_predicate/1) to check if the predicate exists to avoid an exception if it does not. functor/3 could probably be used but somewhere I recall a corner case that it did now work. The rest should not need explaining.

I only entered 3 of the male facts. Would have used all of them if they were typed as text into the question as then they could have been easily copied.

If the facts are in a different module remember to change the name of the module when calling list_facts/N.

```
:- module(examples,
    [
        list_facts/1,
        list_facts/2,
        list_facts/3
    ]).


:- dynamic female/1.

:- dynamic male/1.

male(saad).
male(sohaib).
male(salman).

list_facts(Module:Name/Arity) :-
    list_facts(user_output,Module:Name/Arity,[]).

list_facts(Output_stream,Module:Name/Arity) :-
    list_facts(Output_stream,Module:Name/Arity,[]).

list_facts(Output_stream,Module:Name/Arity,Options) :-
    (
        current_predicate(Module:Name/Arity)
    ->
        (
            option(left_margin_size(Left_margin_size),Options)
        ->
            atomic_list_concat(['~|~',Left_margin_size,'+~|~w'],Format)
        ;
            Format = '~w'
        ),
        (
            option(title(Title),Options)
        ->
            format(Output_stream,Format,[Title]),
            format(Output_stream,'~n',[])
        ;
            true
        ),
        functor(Head,Name,Arity),
        forall(
            rule(Module:Head,Rule),
            list_fact(Output_stream,Format,Rule)
        )
    ;
        format(Output_stream,'No facts found: ~w:~w/~w.~n',[Module,Name,Arity])
    ).

list_fact(Output_stream,Format,Fact) :-
    Fact =.. Fact_values,
    list_values(Output_stream,Format,false,Fact_values).

% Recursive case - functor name
list_values(Output_stream,Format,false,[_Value|Values]) :-
    !,
    list_values(Output_stream,Format,true,Values).

% Recursive case - fact arguments
list_values(Output_stream,Format,true,[Value|Values]) :-
    !,
    format(Output_stream,Format,[Value]),
    list_values(Output_stream,Format,true,Values).

% Base case
list_values(Output_stream,_Format,_Functor_done,[]) :-
    format(Output_stream,'~n',[]).
```

Example usage.

```
?- working_directory(_,'C:/Users/Groot').
true.

?- [examples].
true.

?- list_facts(examples:male/1).
saad
sohaib
salman
true.


?- list_facts(user_output,examples:male/1,[left_margin_size(3),title('male/1')]).
   male/1
   saad
   sohaib
   salman
true.
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about [rule](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=rule/2)/2. To keep up-to-date with SWI-Prolog is not easy...

Comment: @CapelliC You're telling me! I learned a lot from you, especially how to use higher level predicates and working with web sites. While I use the docs daily I don't read them to understand SWI-Prolog, instead I read the actual code from [trusted repositories](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/useful-prolog-references/1089#github-24) and check the [commits](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/commits/master) regularly. It is amazing how much is there that is not noted in the docs.

Comment: OT: recently I tried to lookup in swi-prolog.discourse topics about CORS and pengines (seems the pengines.js client doesn't work anymore), but I got a list of unrelated topics - at least, the word CORS not is there... will try better right now...

Comment: This is a lot of code without obvious purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this in **swi-prolog** (and also in **gnu-prolog**) is to use predicate [`listing/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=listing/1):

```
?- listing(male/1).
:- dynamic male/1.

male(saad).
male(sohaib).
male(salman).
...
true.
```

If you want more control over display [formatting](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2), you can define your own predicate as:

```
list_facts(Name/Arity) :-
    functor(Head, Name, Arity),
    forall( clause(Head, true), 
            format('~w.\n', [Head]) ). % Adjust formatting here!
```

Example:

```
?- list_facts(female/1).
female(rida).
female(florida).
female(yasmeen).
...
true.
```

If you want to show just the names, try:

```
?- forall(female(Name), format('~w\n', [Name])).
rida
florida
yasmeen
...
true.
```

**REMARK** The swi-prolog built-in predicate [`forall/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)is defined as:

```
forall(Cond, Action) :-
    \+ (Cond, \+ Action).
```